# AngularJS - apply CSS class on first visible element (Prefer No JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an horizontal list of folders.
I want to have a margin-left between folders(for spacing) but i dont want it to apply on the first item (so there will be no space from screen).
The problem is that 'first-child' applies on **hidden** elements as well.
how can i apply a class on the **first visible item** in list without using jQuery ?

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li ng-repeat="folder in viewmodel.folders" id="folder" class="folder"
      ng-show="folder.role == '13' || folder.role == '14'" ng-click="bringChildren(folder)" loading-directive>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="folderIcon {{ folder.nameKey }}"></div>
    <div class="folderName">{{ folder.displayName }}</div>
    <div class="itemsCounter"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to just use margin-right? If you don't have anything else after your list, it could be a possible solution.

Comment: Have you considering using a filter on your list, instead of `ng-show`?

Comment: well the margin-right could be a solution however i have other inline elements so there is a problem

Comment: what do you mean filter on your list? do filter on ng-repeat? I was not familiar with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) rather than ngShow, since ngIf actually adds/removes the element from the DOM based on the specified condition. Then your first-child CSS selector will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

with CSS selector you especifiq what item you aplicate the style.
use padding-left: 15px; in full elements of uoy list and the first child padding-left: none and this sobrewrite.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-class like the follow and get the first element by queryselector and change the style.

```
<li ng-repeat="folder in viewmodel.folders" id="folder" 
  ng-show="folder.role == '13' || folder.role == '14'" ng-click="bringChildren(folder)" loading-directive  ng-class="{element:folder.role == '13' || folder.role == '14',folder:true}">
```

and then apply style like this.

```
document.querySelector(".element").style.marginLeft=0;
```

Comment: Hi bala thanks for quick reply ! however i need this to apply only for the first item and not for both

Comment: queryselector selects the first element only.  So the style will only apply to first element